# How do I use regex to match on a string that does not contain one of multiple specific words?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I use regular expressions to avoid matching strings containing one of multiple specific words?

For example: a string should contain neither the words `test`, nor `sample`:

```
^((?!(sample|test)).)*$
```

My regular expression is failing in some situations:

```
1. this is a test case 
2. this is a testing area
```

In the above two examples:

1. It has the word `test` so it worked fine.
2. It doesn't have the word `test` it should be allowed

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `\b` around the words so they allow matching, ONLY if they are not present as whole words. Try using this,

```
^(?:(?!\b(sample|test)\b).)*$
```

Also, it is a good idea to make a group as non-capturing, unless you intend to use their value.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oc00Hc/1)**

**Edit:**

For making it case sensitive, enable the `i` flag by placing `i` just after `/` in regex. JS demo,

```js
var arr = ['this is a test case','this is a testing area','this is a Test area']

arr.forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + /^(?:(?!\b(sample|test)\b).)*$/i.test(s)))
```

Comment: how to make it work in a case sensitive conditions like  this is a Test case,

Comment: You can place `i` after `/` in the regex like `/regex/i` and make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex (Word boundry '\b' is necessary and also arbitrary number of characters can be present before those sample words):

```
/^(?!.*?\b(sample|test)\b)/
```

it will match the empty string too because that doesn't contain sample or test word. To check if the string must not be empty and doesn't contain sample and test word then use :

```
/^(?!.*?\b(sample|test)\b).+?/
```

Comment: matches however match is an empty string anchored et the beginning of the line

Comment: @Nahuel Fouilleul  Yes it will match the empty string which by the way does not contain sample or test word. This is required i guess.

Comment: indeed it's more efficient that the tempered greedy token in the question