# How to use jQuery Validate pattern rule to only allow words that are not in a case insensitive list

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am trying to stop spambots from submitting my registration form by only allowing terms that do not match a case insensitive list.  I need the inverse of the `pattern` below. I've read about the `?!` quantifier but I don't understand how to apply it in this case.

I would also like to simplify the list and remove the "Earning" by applying a case insensitive match to the entire list.

```
$("#txtFName").rules("add", { 
   required: true, 
   pattern: /(\.tk|\.nl|per day|per week|Earning|earning|blogspot)/, 
   messages: { 
      required: "First Name must not be blank", 
      pattern: "First Name must not contain invalid words"}
   }
);
```

**UPDATE:** After posting I found [this helpful SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918348/regex-does-not-contain-multiple-words) which handles the negation. So the pattern above should be:

```
   pattern: /^(?:(?!\b(\.tk|\.nl|per day|per week|earning|blogspot)\b).)*$/,
```

However, I still don't see where the `/i` case insensitive modifier should be placed.

Comment: Please try to avoid the tag-spam.  Edited.  Thanks.  Also note that the regex tag triggers a very specific warning list of requirements that your question fails to follow.

Comment: @Sparky I don't think I added the tag-spam so I'm not sure what you mean there. Even though I had the tag-jquery-validate, I just added the javascript tag since I think you mean that a language tag is required when tag-regex is present. However, that is the only requirement I've seen so I don't know what you mean by a "list of requirements".

Answer (score 0):

After reading more and hacking away at it for a while I figured out that to impose a case insensitive comparison on the entire regex, the pattern should end with the `i` modifier. So the entire insensitive, negated `pattern:` should be:

```
pattern: /^(?:(?!\b(\.tk|\.nl|per day|per week|earning|blogspot)\b).)*$/i,
```